Find Column Size (Including TOASTed values) in Postgres
I'm trying to find the total size of a column, including TOASTed values. From my understanding, pg_column_size returns the size of the column, minus the TOASTed values.
I want the actual size of the column: TOAST and all.
I tried to see whether the related TOAST table has some way of grouping by column, but the chunk_id contains no information about the column.

After poking around a bit, I found that pg_column_size does account for TOASTed values.
The first comment on this post lead me to believe otherwise... was pg updated since the post was published?

No. The code is the same: if (typlen == -1)         {                 /* varlena type, possibly toasted */                 result = toast_datum_size(value);         } . The comment was wrong.

The comment was not objecting to the use of pg_column_size in the numerator, but rather to the use of pg_relation_size in the denominator.

Do you want the uncompressed size, or the compressed size (for when compression is in use)?  When a value is fragmented over many rows in the toast table, are you trying to include the row overhead?

@jjanes I'm looking for the uncompressed size.
Out of curiosity, is it possible to do this without doing a full table scan?
I find pg_column_size gets pretty slow on tables with 100K rows.
